# Error $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated, use the php://input stream instead."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mamp

Using PHP 5.6.2 on MAMP. I upgraded Laravel from 4.1 to 4.2, after fixing some errors and changes as described in Laravel's upgrade docs, I finally get this error:

`"Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead."`

Why is that? Where should I change any code? I am not using `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` anywhere in my code.

I also changed my php.ini as stated, same error... How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe laravel uses it?

Comment: And? What should I do about it? I just updated. Docs say "Laravel 4.2 requires PHP 5.4.0 or greater."

Comment: Did you restart Apache/PHP after changing it in php.ini ? Are you sure you updated the right php.ini ? (See the used path with `phpinfo()`). I never used Laravel but you shouldn't have to fix the code in the Framework source, if the `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` comes from Laravel.

Comment: yes I restarted and changed the correct ini

Comment: Well it's a bug in laravel I would mail them.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you. I double checked and made a mistake in my php.ini. Now it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem was editing the right `php.ini`. Then everything worked.

Comment: I changed my php.ini, and it reflected this in phpInfo, but I'm still getting this same error every time I try to do a certain step on a tutorial with json web tokens

Comment: Good answer, but on a more frightening note: will Laravel 5 not run on the upcoming PHP 7?

Comment: Laravel is currently being run on PHP7 dev builds.

Comment: Edit what in PHP ini ??

Answer (score 2):

Please use :

```
Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

To solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your PHP.ini and search to "always_populate_raw_post_data" and set the value to -1, like:

```
; Always populate the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA variable. PHP's default behavior is
; to disable this feature and it will be removed in a future version.
; If post reading is disabled through enable_post_data_reading,
; $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is *NOT* populated.
; http://php.net/always-populate-raw-post-data
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```